# Start function on timeout in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timeout

I need to change the value of title of button just for 2 seconds and after i should return the title back.

I'm changing the title in code below:

```
[self.loginField.titleLabel setText:@"New Text"];
```

So how can i change back the title to "Old Text" in 2 seconds? Is there a "timeout" function with callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
[self.loginField.titleLabel performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"Old Text" afterDelay:2.0];
```